# Load result from requests.get into django template (tableau)?

Tags: python, django, django-templates, tableau-api

I've got a super tiny (one view) django application that loads a view from a tableau server.

I've got it working with the [trust app method](https://help.tableau.com/current/server-linux/en-us/trusted_auth_testing.htm) of connection and if I just put the URL into a browser it loads up okay without issue.

When I try to render that same page inside of a django template however - django tries to load all the resources as if they existed locally (which doesn't work).

The view looks like this:

```
def index(request):
    url = os.environ.get("tableau_HOST")
    username = request.user.username
    ticket = get_tableau_ticket(url, username)
    if ticket:
        data = requests.get(url+ticket+'/views/SIPPlan/DashboardView', data={'username': username})
        print(data.text)
    else:
        # Handle the error - not implemented yet
        r = ticket
    return render(
        request,
        "tableau/index.html",
        {
            "tableau_data": data.text,
        },
    )
```

Inside my template it looks like this:

```
{% extends "myapp/base_template.html" %}
{% load static %}
{% block content %}
    {% autoescape off %}
        {{ tableau_data }}
    {% endautoescape %}
{% endblock %}
```

When I load the view - I see it trying to load the resources from my local machine (which it shouldn't, they exist on the tableau server).

```
[09/Aug/2019 08:26:28] "GET /vizql/v_201921906211547/javascripts/formatters-and-parsers.en_US.js HTTP/1.1" 404 3610
Not Found: /vizql/v_201921906211547/javascripts/vqlweb.js
2019-08-09 08:26:28,639 - django.request       WARNING  Not Found: /vizql/v_201921906211547/javascripts/vqlweb.js
[09/Aug/2019 08:26:28] "GET /vizql/v_201921906211547/javascripts/vqlweb.js HTTP/1.1" 404 3544
Not Found: /vizql/v_201921906211547/javascripts/require.min.js
2019-08-09 08:26:28,700 - django.request       WARNING  Not Found: /vizql/v_201921906211547/javascripts/require.min.js

...etc...
```

But again - if I just hit that URL that I build in a browser (not embedded in a template) it renders fine.

So I guess my question is: is there a good way to render another HTML page inside of a django template page? I can't seem to figure out how to go about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To embed Tableau, you're supposed to either use their [embed code (script tag)](https://help.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-gb/shareworkbooks.htm#shareworkbooks.html)
 or use the [Tableau JS API](https://help.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-gb/embed_code.htm#use-tableau-javascript). Under the hood, either route ends up creating an iframe with the view's URL among other things.

What you're doing is getting the HTML from Tableau and inserting it into your webpage on the server side, which is then served from your Django server. When the assets referenced by that HTML try to load, it looks at your Django server instead of the Tableau server since that's where it was served from.

Instead of requesting the HTML on the server side, just put the embed code in your page (including the trusted token, see [Tableau's Docs](https://help.tableau.com/current/server/en-us/trusted_auth_webURL.htm) for how to do this) and let Tableau's embed scripts handle it.